# Any way to select unique values from values within a row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

My sample data looks like this:

```
A1   A2   B1  B2  
1    2    2    3  
4    5    5    7  
5    4    1    4
```

and my goal is to extract the data like this

```
result1 result2  
1       3  
4       7  
5       1
```

- A1, A2 and B1, B2 are the same columns from different tables (i.e., they have the same attribute names
- Every row has a duplicate value that is in the pair (A1, A2) AND (B1,B2). My goal is to extract the other two values; one from each pair
- I understand how to operate on distinct values across rows, but not within a row.

Is this at all possible? Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: Your table has a design problem, because all the useful aggregate functions which MySQL has, and which could easily be used to answer your question, act across _rows_, not across columns.  If you can provide a column which contains a row ID, or something equivalent, then we can give you a workaround, but really you should just fix your design.

Comment: OK. I'll try to find a better strategy to execute this query. I'm about 5 subqueries deep at this point and this was the last step. I have a solution now, but I agree that there is probably a much better way to approach my problem. I'll keep thinking about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Is this at all possible?*

Yes it is possible(I've assumed that you have a column that uniquely identify a row):

```
SELECT id
     ,MIN(CASE WHEN g=1 THEN c END) AS result1
     ,MIN(CASE WHEN g=2 THEN c END) AS result2
FROM (
SELECT id,c,MIN(g) AS g
FROM (SELECT id, A1 AS c, 1 AS g FROM tab UNION ALL 
      SELECT id, A2, 1 FROM tab UNION ALL 
      SELECT id, B1,2 FROM tab UNION ALL 
      SELECT id, B2,2 FROM tab) sub
GROUP BY id, c
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) s
GROUP BY id;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=638ff805ae91dbfb2a9b2b6d46080183)**

Output:

```
┌────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ id │ result1 │ result2 │
├────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│  1 │       1 │       3 │
│  2 │       4 │       7 │
│  3 │       5 │       1 │
└────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

---

## EDIT

Actually it is even simpler:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN g1_min IN(g2_min, g2_max) THEN g1_max ELSE g1_min END AS result1
      ,CASE WHEN g2_min IN(g1_min, g1_max) THEN g2_max ELSE g2_min END AS result2
FROM (SELECT LEAST(A1,A2) g1_min,GREATEST(A1,A2) g1_max
            ,LEAST(B1,B2) g2_min,GREATEST(B1,B2) g2_max
      FROM tab) s;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a66f4d7072b0152a1aaf7e5fd43fc7fc)**

---

## EDIT2:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN A1 IN (B1, B2) THEN A2 ELSE A1 END AS result1
     , CASE WHEN B1 IN (A1, A2) THEN B2 ELSE B1 END AS result2
FROM tab;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fd51c3cda298d7242f22000371ceb418)**

Answer (score 0):

If you have just 4 columns, you can do it like this. In case some rows dont match your criteria, it will return a -404 error.

```
select 
case 
    when a1=b1 or a1=b2 then a2
    when a2=b1 or a2=b2 then a1
    else -404
end as result1,
case 
    when b1=a1 or b1=a2 then b2
    when b2=a1 or b2=a2 then b1
    else -404
end as result2
from your_table
```